# Can not use RedirectToPage() in get method and cannot show the correct partial view after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using .Net Mvc and recently I found after I logout, the header navbar still showing the logout button, my problem is exactly like the one in this article https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-22-razor-pages-logout-behavior and the only difference is my logout logic is in OnGet() method, and once the RedirectToPage() is used in get method, an infinity loop error will be showed. Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
```

Test Result:
[image]